# Is there a mechanism within LDAP to query out the version of the directory server?

Tags: oracle, ldap

Is there a mechanism to describe/discover information about the directory server implementation using the LDAP protocol itself?  For example if you want to find out the specific version of the product being used on the backend.

As an analogy - in Oracle DBMS you can issue the following SQL to get the version information of the database you are connected to:

```
Select * from v$version
```

The JDBC protocol has a similar mechanism to get Database metadata.  Does the LDAP protocol have any similar discovery features to find out information about the directory server being connected to?  In my particular case I happen to know that the backend Directory server is Oracle/OID but is there a mechanism to describe the directory server using the LDAP protocol itself?  Alternatively is there an Oracle/OID specific technique?

Comment: In a typical corporate environment, the AD server (Domain Controller) is going to be a completely separate entity from the Web Server. For that reason alone, I would think that no such method exists as Windows Servers are locked down pretty tight.

Answer (score 1):

See ["the root dse"](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/the-root-dse.html). Directory Servers might publish this info. See also RFC3045.

#### update:

In java:

```
LDAPConnection conn = new LDAPConnection(hostname,port);
SearchRequest req = new SearchRequest("",SearchScope.BASE,"(&)","+");
SearchResult result = conn.search(req);

// If the search succeeds, the result will comprise one entry,
// and that entry is the Root DSE:

dn: 
subschemaSubentry: cn=schema
namingContexts: C=us
vendorName: UnboundID Corp.
vendorVersion: UnboundID Directory Server 4.1.0.6
```

Answer (score 1):

Although Terry Gardner's solution works on many LDAP server implementations, unfortunately,  version information is a broad and inconsistently supported among LDAP server implementations.

We show some of the [more extensive methods to determine the vendor and versions](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Determine%20LDAP%20Server%20Vendor).

-jim